# Tagging image on facebook using Graph API on C# SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, tagging

I am trying to tag an image using facebook SDK v6 (can be found [here](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx).)
I using the following code trying to achieve this:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(k_OfflineAccess);
fb.PostTaskAsync("/{**photo id**}/tags/", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "to", "{user user to be tagged id}" } });
```

However, I keep get an exception thrown:

*{"(OAuthException) (#322) Invalid photo tag subject"}*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the right data with your request. You can see the correct format on Facebook's docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

The correct url post format is:

```
PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID
```

With the Faceboook C# SDK you would do this like:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(k_OfflineAccess);
fb.PostTaskAsync("/{**photo id**}/tags/", new { to = "{user user to be tagged id}" });
```

Comment: Can you use something like fiddler and provide me with the exact JSON that is sent and received?